# Sync Two MediaWikis weekly?

Tags: php, mysql, mediawiki, wikipedia

We have two mediawiki (like wikipedia) installations. One is public and one is internal.

We do the normal work with the internal adding/changing/deleting text articles and pictures.

We want to sync and update the external one on weekly bases, what is the best approach?

note: We are using 2 windows servers (but willing to change to linux (1 or 2 server setup) if that will make it easier)

cheers

Comment: What particular wiki software are you using? It depends on specific software.

Comment: And are you using a database, or store the wiki data file based?

Comment: MediaWiki is database-based. Most popular and best supported is mySQL, but others work too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Kaestur Hakari writes, the content is in a database, so just make a database dump in an appropriate format from the first database and load that into the second one.

Comment: hi,

yes I just made a btach file that automate the work :-)

cheers